# Hidden SSID plus WPA2

Tags: security, wifi-configuration, ssid

Will using hidden SSID compromise WiFi security in some way when WPA2 and fixed MAC-addresses access list are enabled?

Comment: What I think about this (I might be wrong): not broadcasting SSID is fine in itself for the AP. What is not fine is the fact that clients configured to use a hidden SSID have to blindly try to discover if it's present, thus uselessly sending probes. Hidden SSIDs should not be configured to be used automatically.

Comment: If you have proper WPA2 security and a very strong password, there is not much gained by hiding the SSID except from idle close passersby.

Answer (score 1):

So by your question it sounds like you are asking whether it should be hidden ***or*** encrypted rather than both.

A "hidden" network is [still essentially discoverable](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-discover-hidden-wireless-network/), so if you are relying on that to provide any measure of security then that is not what it does or is for at all. It will still transmit data and interfere with other wifi networks and the signal will be able to be seen by wifi scanner applications.

A hidden network without a password is effectively the same as a network without a password. Any computer will be able to connect, see network traffic, and potentially connect to any computers on that network. They would be able to use your printers, copy files from your NAS or file shares if they are set up without passwords and use your internet connection to pirate all the copyrighted material they can find, all in your name.

Hiding a network is not a security method. It is an illusion of security akin to putting a key under your door mat and a sign saying "the key is NOT under the door mat" on your front door.

Using WPA2 will encrypt the data on the network, meaning that people will only be able to connect if they have the passcode. They will not have access unless you give it to them.

You can hide a WPA2 network, but its presence will still be able to be detected. It *is* still encrypted and thus secure, but hiding it is subject to the same caveat as above in that it is still essentially discoverable by anyone who really wants to find out about it.

The only real reason to hide your network would be to make it easier to find networks people *should* connect to by removing clutter from the "discoverable" network list. If there are lots of networks nearby and one says "THIS ONE" then it is easier to find if most of them are hidden.

Comment: Worth pointing out that an access list of MAC addresses is sent unencrypted.  So a whitelist really isn’t a security feature just an administrative feature.  Disabling DHCP and manually assigning IP addresses to a device is also an Administrative feature.

Comment: I read your question the same way; perhaps you should clarify the question rather than be rude to someone who took the time to answer. Basically Hiding the SSID & using MAC access lists are a false sense of security - the key is under the mat. Don't bother with them.

Comment: @Paul I stated what I *thought* you meant, and then went on to state the difference between one or the other, as well as why you might want both. If I have not answered your question then please explain what it is that I am misunderstanding rather than just getting angry.

Comment: To answer one of your direct questions: "Will the hidden SSID still break my security in this case?" I stated "You can hide a WPA2 network, but its presence will still be able to be detected." as in the WPA2 is doing it's job of encrypting, but *hiding* it is subject to the same caveat that is it still essentially discoverable *yet encrypted and as such is secure*. Hiding and encrypting are two distinct features and have different purposes. I have edited to clarify.